# Why does athena:GetDataCatalog fails for the default "AwsDataCatalog"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

When I list the data catalogs from athena I get:

```
aws athena list-data-catalogs
{
    "DataCatalogsSummary": [
        {
            "CatalogName": "AwsDataCatalog",
            "Type": "GLUE"
        }
    ]
}
```

So there is data catalog named `AwsDataCatalog` which I learned is the default AWS Glue Data Catalog.

I can use `AwsDataCatalog` in

```
aws athena list-databases --catalog-name AwsDataCatalog
```

If I try to perform `GetDataCatalog` on it I get `DataCatalog AwsDataCatalog` was not found`

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.9.12 Python/3.11.1 Darwin/21.6.0 source/x86_64 prompt/off

aws athena get-data-catalog --name AwsDataCatalog

An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the GetDataCatalog operation: DataCatalog AwsDataCatalog was not found.
```

Is this the expected behaviour or I'm doing something wrong?

I would expected that it would give something like

```
{
    "DataCatalog": {
        "Name": "AwsDataCatalog",
        "Description": "Default Data Catalog",
        "Type": "GLUE",
        "Parameters": {
            "catalog_id": "<my-aws-account-id>",

        }
    }
}
```

In any case I just want to know if that is the expected behavior (as in it's the same for everybody else). As I know the response for `AwsDataCatalog` is always going to be `GLUE` so there is no point on actually doing `GetDataCatalog` on it.